# What is this importance of the mist that appears in the hospital corridor?

Tags: plot-explanation, if-i-stay

In Movie "If I Stay (2014)", Some White mist appeared twice in hospital corridors.

[image]

What is this importance of this mist? Does it indicate anything?

Comment: that looks like the gateway to the afterlife, if she chooses to go there. i believe it appears in those moments when she is weakest?